# Tangent to circle creating angle with $y$ axis

Tags: geometry

Why is angle $PCA$ = angle $AEO$ ?

I know why line $EC$ is a bisector, but not why the above is true.

[image]

Comment: Both angles have $\widehat{EAO}$ as a complementary angle.

Answer (score 1):

Well $EOCP$ has to right angles, so $OCP=180°-OEP$. But obviously $OCP=180°-ACP$, so $APC=OEP$.

Answer (score 0):

$APC$ and $EOA$ are similar (rectangle) triangles and they have angle $A$ in common so the other angle needs to be the same too.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$PC$ is orthogonal to $AE$ and $AO$ is orthogonal to $EO$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Notice, sum of all interior angles in a triangle is $180^\circ$

Now, in triangles $\triangle PCA$ & $\triangle AEO$

1. $\angle AOE=\angle APC=90^\circ$
2. $\angle OAE=\angle CAP$ (same angle)

$\triangle PCA \sim \triangle AEO$